# Nginx content_by_lua_block deletes request body?

Tags: nginx, post, lua, request, openresty

I wanted to make some changes on existing nginx configuration. My previous configuration was like this:

```
    location /serviceprovider {

            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

Then I added content_by_lua_block as below:

```
 location /serviceprovider {

            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect off;

            content_by_lua_block{
                    ngx.req.read_body()
                    body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
                    file = io.open("/etc/nginx/test", "w")
                    file:write(body)
                    file:close()
            }
    }
```

My /serviceprovider actually accepts JSON request in POST. When I send request after adding lua block I get error message "Invalid JSON: Empty string", but It writes request body to file successfully.

I think this lua block deletes request body after writing it to file. I only want that location block worked as usual but in addition to write request body to a file.

Comment: `proxy_pass` and `content_by_lua_block` work in content phase, you can only use one content phase handler, for this case, I think you can use `access_by_lua_block` instead of `content_by_lua_block`

Comment: I used rewrite_by_lua_block instead of content_by_lua_block and it worked. Anyway, thanks for answer